# jquery, move an inner element to the first position?

Tags: jquery, html, sorting

Lets say you have a list of items:

```
<ul id="ImportantNumbers">
   <li id="one"></li>
   <li id="two"></li>
   <li id="topNumber"></li>
   <li id="four"></li>
</ul>
```

Every five seconds these list items get reordered.

Using **jquery** whats the best way to keep `#topNumber`, at the top of the list during the reordering.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can use [`.prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/) immediately after the re-order, like this:

```
$("#topNumber").prependTo("#ImportantNumbers");
```

[You can see it working here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/vjxnR/), all it's doing is taking the element and inserting it as the first child on the `<ul>`, effectively moving it to the top.

Alternatively when you sort, use [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to exclude it depending on how the sorting works, for example:

```
$("#ImportantNumbers li:not(#topNumber)").randomize();
```