# Move opened page link to the top of the list

Tags: html, css, list

I have a sidebar with a list of a categories in my site. Opened category always has .current-cat class and is highlighted and stuff.

What i want to do:

Is it possible to move items which belong to .current-cat classs to the top of the list?

All the elements are li.

Thanks.

Comment: You are going to have to use JavaScript and jQuery would be even more helpful.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use jQuery, you can use prependTo like this :

```
$("ul#yourId").prependTo( $("ul#yourId .current-cat");
```

Otherwise, we need an example to see what is your goal.

Check this link to more information : [jquery, move an inner element to the first position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506140/jquery-move-an-inner-element-to-the-first-position)

[Or click here to see this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/vjxnR/)